# How clean does concrete floor really need to be for peel and stick flooring?

Tags: concrete, flooring

We bought an older home and found that there were two layers of peel and stick flooring in the bathroom. We removed those and this is the result of the floor after scraping and scrubbing for hours. My question is does all of that stuff still need to come off? It doesn't feel different to the touch from the bare spot of concrete in the corner, will that truly make the peel and stick not work as well? We've tried sanding to no avail, some suggested using oil based cleaners to remove it, others say absolutely do NOT use oil based, so we can't get a consistent answer from anyone.

Also there are a couple very very small chips, do those need to be filled in or will they be unnoticeable? Will the sealer we are going to put on pre-stick make that a non-issue? Do we even need a sealer?[image]

thanks for any help!

Comment: How did it go? Or do you still have a concrete floor? :D

Comment: We scrubbed quite a bit, wasn't perfect. But the flooring we got was a floating laminate floor plank with built in underlayment, baseboard and cabinet holds it down just fine, haven't had a problem since we put it in